# send arguments from system plugin to model plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

How to send a message from a system plugin to a model plugin. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

I want to send arguments to the model plugin. And I run this plugin in server side.

```
#include <gazebo/math/Rand.hh>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace gazebo
{
  typedef const boost::shared_ptr<const msgs::Vector2d> VectorTwoDPtr;

  class CommandLine : public SystemPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      for(int i =0; i<argc; i++)// I want to send the arguments to the model plugin
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
      this->connections.push_back( event::Events::ConnectPreRender( boost::bind(&CommandLine::Update, this)));
     }

private: void Init()
{
  transport::NodePtr nodePub = transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());
  nodePub->Init();
  transport::PublisherPtr  publisher = nodePub->Advertise<msgs::Vector2d>("~/robotName");

  math::Vector2d vect( 2, 1);   
  msgs::Vector2d msg;
  msgs::Set(&msg, vect);
  publisher->Publish(msg);
}
private: void Update()
{
  // the onUpdate don't work 
}
private: std::vector<event::ConnectionPtr> connections;
  };
  GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(CommandLine) 
}
```

THANK YOU !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8969/send-arguments-from-system-plugin-to-model-plugin-?/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I solved the problem, here is what I did:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
using namespace std;
namespace gazebo 
{ 
  class systemPlugin : public SystemPlugin 
  {    

    public: void Load(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
      robotName= argv[argc-1];
    }
    private: virtual void Init()
    {

      node=transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());
      node->Init();
      pub = node->Advertise<msgs::GzString>("~/robotName");

      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          boost::bind(&systemPlugin::OnUpdate, this));      
    }
    private: virtual void OnUpdate()
    {
       msgs::GzString msg;
       msg.set_data(robotName);
       pub->Publish(msg);
    }
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;

    transport::NodePtr node;
    transport::PublisherPtr pub;
    string robotName;
 };

  GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(systemPlugin)
}
```

---

Originally posted by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) with karma: 78 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1